# My Gateway is hanging on POST requests that get forwarded to another port, GET requests seem to work

Tags: node.js, express, http, proxy, gateway

I have a basic gateway that forwards client requests to the services that they are meant for. The services are listening on their own different ports (Authentication and API). When I send a GET request via the gateway to Authentication or API service, it works as expected. However, when I send a POST request it seems to be that the request keeps hanging.
NOTE: Sending the requests directly to the Authentication or API port (so not through the gateway) works fine for both GET and POST.

EDIT: After browsing posts with the similar topic I also noticed that gateway POST requests work when I leave the body empty.

Here is my basic gateway logic:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import ApiRedirectService from '../services/api-redirect.service';
import AuthenticationRedirectService from '../services/authentication-redirect.service';

export default class IndexController {
  private apiRedirectService: ApiRedirectService = new ApiRedirectService();
  private authenticationRedirectService: AuthenticationRedirectService =
    new AuthenticationRedirectService();
  constructor() {}

  public index = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const currentDate = '[' + new Date().toUTCString() + ']';
      console.log(`${currentDate}:\n[${req.method}]: ${req.path}\n`);

      if (req.path.startsWith('/api')) {
        this.apiRedirectService.redirectToApi(req, res, next);
      } else if (req.path.startsWith('/auth')) {
        this.authenticationRedirectService.redirectToAuthentication(
          req,
          res,
          next
        );
      } else {
        // redirect to an error page or throw something?
        res
          .status(200)
          .send(
            `<p style="text-align: center;">This is the <b>index</b> endpoint of the Gateway server.</p>`
          );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Here's the redirect service for the Authentication service:

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import { AUTHENTICATION_HOSTNAME, AUTHENTICATION_PORT } from '../config';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

class AuthenticationRedirectService {
  constructor() {
    //
  }

  public redirectToAuthentication(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): void {
    this.proxyAuthentication(req, res, next);
    console.log('testerer');
  }

  private proxyAuthentication(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): void {
    const proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
      target: `http://${AUTHENTICATION_HOSTNAME}:${AUTHENTICATION_PORT}`,
      changeOrigin: true,
      timeout: 5000, // Adjust the timeout value as needed (in milliseconds)
    });

    // Pass the request body to the proxy for POST requests
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      proxy(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send('Proxy Error');
        }
      });
    } else {
      // For GET requests, you can simply call proxy() without specifying the method.
      proxy(req, res, next);
    }
  }
}

export default AuthenticationRedirectService;
```

And here is my Authentication service's controller that is supposed to get hit by the gateway POST request and return the response there.

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import IdentityService from '../services/identity.service';

export default class AuthController {
  public identityService: IdentityService = new IdentityService();
  constructor() {}

  public getIdentities = async (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await this.identityService.getAllIdentities();
      res.status(response.statusCode).json(response);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };

  public createIdentity = async (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await this.identityService.createIdentity(req.body);
      res.status(response.statusCode).send(response);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };

}
```

Comment: Could you put list of middlware you are using in your code?! Maybe your problem is about order of middlware. Please see https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/40 issue